# How to create a nice form in HTML

Tags: html, forms, html-input

I am trying to create a form but I am struggling to format the text.

I want to put a "Label/Title" and then the input but I do not succeed. It's my first time using HTML.

`<input type="time" name="time" value="22:00"/> - <input type="time" name="time" value="22:00"/>`

This is just giving me the input but I do not like the format which look like :

[image]

but I would like to get the one below. I do not care for now about the font/size but I would appreciate to have an example

[image]

Any idea how I can create this new style with the bottom line, manage font and size.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Changing the way that HTML output looks is done with something called CSS. You should learn in particular about CSS borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using label tag.Like this,

```
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
```

refer this -> https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit